# Relation of GNU f77/gfortran and f2c?

Tags: gfortran, fortran77, g77

What is the relation of g77/gfortran and f2c today? Is there still development going on? Is one benefiting from the others advances (like bugs and performance)?

Who is developing f2c (if it's not done by the g77/gfortran developers)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

g77 is no longer supported and is not being worked on.  G77 was dropped and Gfortran started being shipped with gcc-4.0 in Apr 20 2005.  The last of the gcc-3.* (with g77) was released officially in Mar 06 2006.

I think the same is true for f2c.  The codebase is on [netlib](http://www.netlib.org/f2c/) and the last changelog entry is 31 Aug. 1989.

All the Gnu development is on gfortran.  Gfortran is supposed to work on Fortran77 code though.  Gfortran is a native compiler (like g77) not a translator like f2c.

Comment: Actually the last change to F2C is from Aug. 1, 2011 (the changes are added to the bottom instead of to the top of the file). However, the last few changes were very minor, and basically F2C seems abandoned.

Comment: I think f2c is dead.  I've had great experiences with gfortran though.  I compile lots of legacy code as well as some new stuff.  Plus it's a real compiler rather than a translator so debugging is easier.